# Difference between Process.WorkingSet64 and Process.PeakWorkingSet64

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have to read the memory usage of my program. I think that Process.WorkingSet64 or Process.PeakWorkingSet64 is the right for that.

Problem: Even with google I cant figure out the exactly difference between this two. Anyone who knows?

[Process.WorkingSet64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.workingset64%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[Process.PeakWorkingSet64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.peakworkingset64%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: PeakWorkingSet is the HIGHEST it's been. WorkingSet is what it is RIGHT NOW. Which one you want depends on your use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difference is quite simple

`Process.PeakWorkingSet64` gives you maximum value of memory assigned to process since it started

on the other hand

`Process.WorkingSet64` gives you current value of memory assigned to process